# Error when bundling application using pyinstaller (windows)

Tags: python, py2exe, pyinstaller

I'm trying to bundle a quite extensive application that uses scikits-image/skimage, numpy, scipy, wx and reportlab. I'm on Windows 7 btw.

It seems to build just fine:

```
1091 INFO: wrote C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\sasdm\sasdm.spec
1200 INFO: Testing for ability to set icons, version resources...
1923 INFO: ... resource update available
1993 INFO: UPX is not available.
12236 INFO: checking Analysis
12246 INFO: building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc non existent
12246 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
12256 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent assemblies of final executabl
e
69579 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.2
1022.8_none ...
69589 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1f
c8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91.manifest
69640 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
69650 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b
_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcr90.dll
69650 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
69660 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b
_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcp90.dll
69660 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll
69660 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b
_9.0.21022.8_none_bcb86ed6ac711f91\msvcm90.dll
70089 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\support\_pyi_bootstrap
.py
72563 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\arc
hive.py
72713 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\car
chive.py
72864 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\iu.
py
72904 INFO: Analyzing C:/Users/IEUser/Desktop/sasdm/sasdm.py
90069 INFO: checking Tree
90078 INFO: building because out00-Tree.toc missing or bad
90078 INFO: building Tree out00-Tree.toc
91530 INFO: checking Tree
91530 INFO: building because out01-Tree.toc missing or bad
91530 INFO: building Tree out01-Tree.toc
98730 INFO: Hidden import 'encodings' has been found otherwise
98742 INFO: Looking for run-time hooks
98742 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\support/rthooks
/pyi_rth_Image.py
98772 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\support/rthooks
/pyi_rth_PIL_Image.py
98802 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\support/rthooks
/pyi_rth_Tkinter.py
98911 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\support/rthooks
/pyi_rth_encodings.py
100013 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of
 final executable
123457 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\sasdm\build
\pyi.win32\sasdm\warnsasdm.txt
123556 INFO: checking PYZ
123556 INFO: rebuilding out00-PYZ.toc because out00-PYZ.pyz is missing
123556 INFO: building PYZ out00-PYZ.toc
155382 INFO: checking PKG
155393 INFO: rebuilding out00-PKG.toc because out00-PKG.pkg is missing
155393 INFO: building PKG out00-PKG.pkg
199075 INFO: checking EXE
199085 INFO: rebuilding out00-EXE.toc because sasdm.exe missing
199085 INFO: building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
199164 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\sasdm\
dist\sasdm.exe
```

But when I try to run the application I am greeted with the following errors:

```
_MEIPASS2 is NULL
archivename is C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\sasdm\dist\sasdm.exe
Extracting binaries
Executing self as child with Setting up to run child
Creating child process
Waiting for child process to finish...
_MEIPASS2 is C:/Users/IEUser/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI39282/
archivename is C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\sasdm\dist\sasdm.exe
Already in the child - running!
manifestpath: C:/Users/IEUser/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI39282/sasdm.exe.manifest
Activation context created
Activation context activated
C:/Users/IEUser/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI39282/python27.dll
Manipulating evironment
PYTHONPATH=C:/Users/IEUser/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI39282;C:/Users/IEUser/Desktop/
pyinstaller/sasdm/dist
PYTHONHOME=C:/Users/IEUser/AppData/Local/Temp/_MEI39282/
importing modules from CArchive
extracted iu
extracted struct
extracted archive
Installing import hooks
out00-PYZ.pyz
Running scripts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 386,
 in importHook
    mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
  File "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480,
 in doimport
    exec co in mod.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\sasdm\build\pyi.win32\sasdm\out00-PY
Z.pyz\cell_analysis", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 431,
 in importHook
    mod = self.doimport(nm, ctx, ctx + '.' + nm)
  File "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480,
 in doimport
    exec co in mod.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\sasdm\build\pyi.win32\sasdm\out00-PY
Z.pyz\skimage.data", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 386,
 in importHook
    mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
  File "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480,
 in doimport
    exec co in mod.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\sasdm\build\pyi.win32\sasdm\out00-PY
Z.pyz\skimage.io", line 76, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\sasdm\build\pyi.win32\sasdm\out00-PY
Z.pyz\skimage.io", line 56, in _update_doc
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
RC: -1 from sasdm
OK.
Deactivating activation context
Releasing activation context
Done
Back to parent...
Freeing status for C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\pyinstaller\sasdm\dist\sasdm.exe
```

This leads me to believe that there's something wrong with skimage / scikits-image but I'm clueless about how to resolve this. Has anyone encountered anything similar?

**UPDATE**

I also tested this with py2exe and got the following sort of identical response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sasdm.py", line 10, in <module>
    import cell_analysis
  File "cell_analysis.pyc", line 13, in <module>

  File "skimage\data\__init__.pyc", line 11, in <module>
  File "skimage\io\__init__.pyc", line 76, in <module>
  File "skimage\io\__init__.pyc", line 56, in _update_doc
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've narrowed the problem down now. In skimage/io/_plugins/plugin.py, skimage will try to read its plugins from files in the following manner:

```
pd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
ini = glob(os.path.join(pd, '*.ini'))
```

However, **file** evaluates to a non-existent (and seemingly randomly named) directory. Now, skimage needs it's plugin files (.ini and .py) to be included in the bundle and then when run, needs to look for them within the bundle. I guess the first bit could be done by collecting data files but the second part?

Comment: We're trying to fix this here: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/1157  Any feedback you have would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with cx_Freeze. My workaround was by just copying whole folder skimage from Python\Lib\site-packages to the folder with the exe file.

Afterwards I got a new error "**ImportError: no module named signal**", which I fixed by adding scipy.signal in the build.

By the way, following error:

```
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

triggered by this line in my code:

```
from skimage import data
```